# Unit testing is necessary for Android SDK application?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am working on a Android application with SDK, my question is: is that necessary to do unit testing?

Answer (score 1):

No it ist not required, but it would be better. So you can see directly If a old feature has been broken by accident.

The only disadvantage is that it cost time to write the tests.